# Agrupar dados JSON (enviados por vários dispositivos) por data

Tags: javascript, json

Estou a trabalhar num projecto com websokets é não sei bem como resolver o seguinte problema.
Eu recebo via WS dados JSON de vários dispositivos.
Cada dispositivo envia um valor uma vez por segundo. No cliente recebo os dados dos vários dispositivos assim.

```
{ab1: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:50", value: "31"}}
{cd2: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:50", value: "34"}}
{ab1: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:51", value: "32"}}
{cd2: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:51", value: "36"}}
...
```

Até agora consegui organizar os dados por id:

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) { 
    var data = JSON.parse(evt.data);
    var id = data.id;
    var date = data.date;
    var value = data.value;
    datas[id] = {'date':date,'value':value};
};
```

o resultado fica assim:

```
{ab1:{date:"2019-06-12 12:45:50",value:"31"}, cd2:{date:"2019-06-12 12:45:50",value:"34"}}
{ab1:{date:"2019-06-12 12:45:51",value:"32"}, cd2:{date:"2019-06-12 12:45:51",value:"36"}}
...
```

Mas como preciso agrupar os dados por data para posteriormente criar a média dos valores recebidos a cada segundo e exibir em um gráfico que actualiza uma vez por segundo. Este formato não facilita.

O ideal seria que os dados acima ficassem no seguinte formato:

```
{2019-06-12 12:45:50: {id: "ab1", value: "31"}, {id: "cd2", value: "34"}}
{2019-06-12 12:45:51: {id: "ab1", value: "32"}, {id: "cd2", value: "36"}}
```

Precisava de uma orientação para converter dos dados recebido neste formato.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se isto te ajuda.

Em vez de retornar cada objeto assim:

```
{2019-06-12 12:45:50: {id: "ab1", value: "31"}, {id: "cd2", value: "34"}}
```

Retorna assim:

```
{date: "2019-06-12 12:45:50": [{id: "ab1", value: "31"}, {id: "cd2", value: "34"}]}
```

Exemplo:

```js
const arr = [

{ab1: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:50", value: "31"}},
{cd2: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:50", value: "34"}},
{ab1: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:51", value: "32"}},
{cd2: {date: "2019-06-12 12:45:51", value: "36"}},

]

const output = [];

arr.forEach(i => {

  const id = Object.keys(i)[0];

  const date = i[id].date, value = i[id].value;

  const obj = output.find(i => i.date === date);

  if(!obj) {

    output.push({date: date, data: [{id: id, value: value}]});

  }

  else {

    obj.data.push({id: id, value: value});

  }

});

document.write(JSON.stringify(output));

console.log(output)
```

Comment: interessante, mas o problema é que as mensagens json chegam uma de cada vez em temo real.
Eu deveria poder processar os dados que vai chegando uma vez por segundo.